# How can I manage two versions of the same service?

Tags: wsdl, wso2

We're looking for a service registry and repository for our company. We're evaluating WSO2 registry right now.

How can we manage two versions of the same service? By version I mean the same logical service (same name) but with diferent WSDLs in each version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is out of the box support for this. If you add a service, then increment the version and change any property (including WSDL) a new version would get created and linked. I could not find a document for the exact process, but hope you can play around and see if you can get it to work.

For docs on adding services look at [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance411/Adding+Services).